# Paypal Adaptive Payments with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I can't seem to find any examples of creating a Paypal Adaptive Payment using Classic ASP. Is there a reason that it cannot be done or preferably could someone provide an example? I would like to see example code where a call to Paypal has returned the Pay Token.

Answer (score 0):

There's this.  I'd have thought it would show up in Google

https://www.x.com/adaptive-payments-19

Comment: Thanks John, that is useful, however it requires a certificate. I have tried to adapt this to use a signature but I keep getting the error Error Type:
msxml6.dll (0x80072F0C)
A certificate is required to complete client authentication